# Security Notice interrupts vba to copy from source to destination if a macro is in the source

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a macro designed to open desired workbooks (I always select 5) and migrate the first sheet into the destination workbook.

4 of the 5 source worksheets have macros.

When I run the code, the following popup appears at the point of copying the worksheet at source. This interrupts the code, leaves the source workbook open and stops running.

I click YES, CONTINUE THE OPERATION, but as the macro has stopped functioning it doesn't migrate the sheet over to my destination.

I have to then run my macro again, reselect the workbook that failed and on the second time, it works.

But the next worksheet has the popup and the error cycle continues.

Any ideas on how I can auto accept/evade this error from interrupting what is otherwise a well functioning bit of code?

[Microsoft Excel Security Notice - MACRO RELATED][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKAvy.png

---

Sub mergeFiles()
'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
'https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/#Method_4_Merge_files_with_a_simple_VBA_macro

```
'turn off screen updating for smoother look and feel
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'To suppress warnings, turn off alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Define variables:
Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

     
'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

  
'Loop through all selected workbooks
For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
    
    'Open each workbook to not update links and as read only
    Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i), False, True
    
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
    sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            
    'Close the source workbook without saving changes in the source workbooks
    sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next i

'Direct macro to unhide all columns and clear all filters
 For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If wks.AutoFilterMode Then wks.AutoFilterMode = False
        wks.Rows.Hidden = False
        wks.Columns.Hidden = False
        Next wks
        
    Call BreakExternalLinks
    
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't *bypass or intercept it*. It's a security feature that prevents malicious code from running. If you could just bypass it, it wouldn't be a security feature. You can configure Excel to allow the macros without the prompt, but that would depend on the user going into Options and enabling those macros to run.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite - I can include a business process to ensure source files have been checked to ensure macros are enabled before executing the macro.Our corporate permissions won't allow for macros to be enabled by default.

Comment: If your corporate permissions won't allow for macros to be enabled by default, you're out of luck. That's the only way to bypass the dialog - by disabling the need to display it in the first place.